# Can you identify these arch-way pieces

Tags: part-identification, building

I'm considering starting a project inspired by some of the Arab-style buildings I've seen. Most of them use a sort of curved archway around the windows. I can't figure out how to duplicate it. Can anyone identify the pieces used here to form the curved archways?

Any other suggestions for making a cool arab scene (for a relatively new builder)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would help the volunteers here if you would include at least part of the picture in your questions, as well as the link to the full version.

Comment: Your question have two questions - looking for parts to identify and ideas for your MOC. If you need suggestion regarding last bit please split this question and submit another question for your inspurations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are, most likely, interested in identifying following arch:

[Brick, Arch 1 x 3 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=88292#T=P)

[image]

The other arch as seen in second picture is the following one:

[Brick, Arch 1 x 3 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=13965#T=P)

[image]